# How do I install wordpress and drupal together in xampp

Tags: wordpress, drupal, xampp, localhost

I have WordPress installed and running on XAMPP local server. I would like to install Drupal too on the same XAMPP server. Is this possible? If yes, **how**? If no, may I ask why impossible?

Comment: It should work fine as long as you aren't trying to serve both pages from the same directory (e.g., http://localhost/). Both WordPress and Drupal use `index.php` to serve content so the Drupal installation would need to be installed in a different directory to function. Give it a shot and if you get stuck with a specific issue ask a new question here.

Answer (score 0):

You could define 2 virtual hosts. Inside your Xampp installation dir should be config file: `\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

And inside it commented row for including vhost file:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Uncomment it. (Include command, not "Virtual hosts" comment, of course)

Then you should create that file. Put content inside:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
DocumentRoot <PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_HERE>
ServerName <SERVER_NAME like local.pos.com>
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY_HERE & SERVER_NAME with appropriate values, Save the file. Since you have 2 projects you'll have to have this section for each.

Then you'll have to edit hosts file. On windows it should be:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

On mac file is: `/private/etc/hosts`

On linux it should be at `/etc/hosts`

Add to that file per each site row like:

```
127.0.0.1      <SERVER_NAME like local.pos.com>
```

https://ultimatefosters.com/hosting/setup-a-virtual-host-in-windows-with-xampp-server/